# Scalar product and Unit vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Prove that, for any unit vectors $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n$ in $\Bbb R^n$, there exists a unit vector $w$ in $\Bbb R^n$ such that $\langle w, v_i \rangle \leq n^{-1/2}$ for all $i=1, 2, \ldots, n$. (Here $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is a usual scalar product in $\Bbb R^n$.)

How can I prove it? It's my first time in linear algebra, so it is not really easy task.

Answer (score 2):

The question, as formulated, has the following uninteresting answer:

Let $S=\text{Span}\{v_2, \dots, v_n\}$. Now take a unit vector $w$ in $S^\perp$. If $\langle w, v_1\rangle\le 0$ you are done, otherwise, replace $w$ by $-w$.

Comment: What if $v_1 \in \text{Span}\{v_2, \dots, v_n\}$? Question doesn't mention that the $v_i$'s form a basis.

Comment: In that case $\langle w, v_1\rangle=0$ which is included in the answer.